# RxJs Window : not getting last observable

Tags: rxjs, reactive-programming

I've written this piece of code,

```
timer(0, 100)
  .pipe(
     windowTime(1000),
     take(3),
     flatMap( value => value.pipe(toArray())))
```

I don't understand why in my subscribe I only get 2 values. Whatever `n` take I always get `n-1` values in my subscribe.

Could you explain to me why ?

Edit: I suspect a bug therefore I [opened a bug](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/5371).

Answer (score 0):

Interesting problem!

So, `windowTime(1000)` will emit a **new window** every 1000ms. But what exactly is a window? A window is `Subject` instance.

`windowTime` can manage multiple windows, but when you're only providing its first argument(called `windowTimeSpan`), there will be **only one** **active window**. What this means is that after `windowTimeSpan` ms pass, the **current window** will be **closed** and a new one will be created and pushed into the stream.

When a window is **closed**, it means that it will send a **complete notification**. This is a very important aspect.

When you subscribe, a window is going to be created **immediately** and pushed into the stream.
By doing `flatMap(value => value.pipe(toArray())))`, you can register observers for the current window(subject). It's semantically the same as `subject.pipe(toArray()).subscribe(subscriber)`

#### Why does it behave this way?

```js
timer(0, 100)
  .pipe(
    // Emit a value(window) every 1000ms and close(complete) the prev one
    windowTime(1000),
    take(3),
    flatMap( value => value.pipe(toArray()))
  )
```

Firstly, let's have a look at `flatMap`. `flatMap` is the same as `mergeMap`. What `mergeMap` does is to manage a number(`concurrent`, defaults to `INFINITY`) of inner observables. An inner observable is being tracked until it `completes`.

What `toArray` does it to accumulate values until its source `completes`. In this case, until the current `subject`(window) `completes`. This happens when a window is closed, more specifically, when `1000ms` pass.

So, as delineated before, a window will be created immediately on subscription.
After `0ms` a value(0) comes in, after `100ms` another value(1) and so forth until value `9` comes in. In the meanwhile all these values were collected by `toArray`. So 9's arrival also marks `1000ms`, that is also when the current window will be closed(will emit a `complete notification`). When this happens, `toArray` will receive the notification and will send the **collected values** to the data consumer.

After this a new window is created(second value for `take(3)`). Then, value 10 comes in, then value 11 and so forth until 19, which marks another `1000ms`, which will cause the current window to complete and a new one to be created. But this new window would represent the 3rd value for `take(3)`. This means that `take` will unsubscribe from its source and will emit a complete notification.

As a result, the source will not be able to receive any other values, so this should explain why you're only getting 2 arrays.

Comment: The complete is never called. That's why we have a bug here.

Comment: I didn’t say it was called. I said it emits a complete notification. And mergeMap will not pass it along because its inner obs did not complete, because its window will not complete. So it might be a bug or not, all I tried was to explain why this happens